# Rudin Chapter 4, Exercise 13

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am having trouble solving exercise 13 of Chapter 4 in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis.* The exercise is quite long, so I'm only focusing for the moment on the initial portion. It states:

> Let $E$ be a dense subset of a metric space $X$, and let $f$. be a uniformly continuous *real* function defined on $E$. Prove that $f$ has a continuous extension from $E$ to $X$.

I am trying to follow the hint he gives. For each $p \in X$ and each positive integer $n$, I let $V_n (p)$ consist of the set of $q \in E$ such that $d(q,p) < 1/n$. There's a problem in Rudin which states that: if $\{E_n\}$ is a sequence of closed nonempty bounded sets in a complete metric space $X$, $E_n \supset E_{n+1}$, and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \text{diam}(E_n) = 0$, then $\bigcap_{1}^{\infty} E_n$ consists of one point. So this is the result I want to move toward citing to show that $\bigcap\limits_{1}^{\infty} \overline{f(V_n (p))}$ consists of a single point. So I'll attempt to show each of the conditions is met:

- **Nonempty**: $E$ is dense in $X$, so for any $\frac{1}{m} > 0$,there exists a point of $E$ in $N_{\frac{1}{m}} (p) \supset V_n (p)$. So $V_n (p)$ is nonempty, so $f(V_n (p))$ is nonempty, so $\overline{f(V_n (p))}$ is nonempty.
- **Closed**: The closure of a set is closed by definition.
- **Bounded**: Each $V_n (p)$ is bounded and $f$ is uniformly continuous, so $f(V_n (p))$ is bounded. So its closure is also bounded.
- **Nested**. If $y \in V_{n+1} (p)$, then $d(p,y) < \frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{n}$, so $y \in V_n (p)$. Then $V_{n+1} (p) \subset V_n (p)$, so $f(V_{n+1})(p) \subset f(V_n (p)$, so the same is true when we take closures.
- **Diameter goes to zero**: $f$ is uniformly continuous on $V_n (p)$. There's a problem in Rudin that states that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(V_n (p)) = 0$. Then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(V_n (p)) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \overline{f(V_n (p))} = 0$.

The five conditions are satisfied, so $\bigcap_{1}^{\infty} \overline{f(V_n (p))}$ consists of a single point. Call it $g(p)$. The claim in the hint in Rudin is that the map produced by this process is a continuous extension into $X$. I think I need to prove: (1) this map agrees with $f$ on $E$ and (2) this map is continuous. I could have begun the construction with a $p \in E^c$ and then defined $g$ to agree with $f$ on $E$. I'm not sure if that's the way to go about this. But if $p \in E$, I think $\bigcap_{1}^{\infty} \overline{\overline{f(V_n (p))}}$ consists only of $f(p)$ and $n \to \infty$, so I think the condition is still met. I am not sure, however, how to prove that $g$ is continuous. I don't think it in general follows that because $f$ is uniformly continuous, $g$ is too.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that in general if $f$ is a uniformly continuous function on a set $E\subset X$ then $f$ can be extended to a continuous function $\overline f$ on $\overline E$ such that $\overline f|_E = f$. This solves your problem because the density of $E$ implies that $\overline E = X$. Here is a sketch of the proof.

Fix a limit point $x$ of $E$. Take a sequence of points $\{x_n\}$ in $E$ with $x_n \to x$. Then we *define* $\overline f$ by $\overline f(x) = \lim f(x_n)$, and the uniform continuity of $f$ and completeness of $\mathbb R$ guarantees that the latter limit exists. To see that $\overline f$ is well-defined, if $y_n \to x$ and $x_n \to x$, then since $|x_n - y_n| \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ the uniform continuity of $f$ guarantees that $|f(y_n) - f(x_n)| \to 0$, hence $\overline f$ is well-defined. The continuity of $f$ on $E$ guarantees that $\overline f|_E = f$, so all that remains to show is that $\overline f$ is continuous on $\overline E$. Fix a sequence of points $\{x_n\}$ in $\overline E$ convering to $x$. Then to each $x_n$ there a is a sequence $\{y_{n,k}\}$ of points in $E$ such that $y_{n,k} \to x_n$ as $k \to \infty$. Then by definition of $\overline f$, for each $n\geq 1$, there is $k_n$ large enough that $|\overline f(x_n) - f(y_{n,k_n})| < n^{-1}$ and $d(x_n, y_{n,k_n}) < n^{-1}$. Then as $n\to \infty$ the sequence $y_{n,k_n} \to x$ as $n\to \infty$. Moreover, $$|\overline f(x_n) - \overline f(x)| \leq |\overline f(x_n) - f(y_{n,k_n})| + |f(y_{n,k_n}) - \overline f(x)| < n^{-1} + |f(y_{n,k_n}) - \overline f(x)|.$$ Taking $n\to \infty$, by definition of $\overline f$ we have $|f(y_{n,k_n}) - \overline f(x)| \to 0$, hence
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} |\overline f(x_n) - \overline f(x)| = 0,$$
so $\overline f$ is continuous on $\overline E$. This proves that $\overline f$ satisfies the specified requirements.